# crystal report shared variable from sub report to main report?

Tags: crystal-reports

in my sub report

```
shared Numbervar myTotal:= SUM({SP_Project;1.alloted}); 
myTotal;
```

and in my main report..a make a formula

```
shared Numbervar myTotal;
SUM({@byAppro},{@byOffice}) + myTotal;
```

and i get the right total..but when i make another formula using the same shared variable

```
shared Numbervar myTotal;
SUM({@byAllo},{@byOffice}) + myTotal;
```

this time it didn't work..the `myTotal` becomes `0` which is it should have the same value from the 1st formula..why is that ? is it ? it can only be use once ?

Comment: Where did you use in the formula before or after the sub report

Comment: after the sub-report mate

Answer (score 1):

The formula that is not working is probably in the same section as the subreport and the formula that IS working is probably in a later section.  Formulas are evaluated before subreports when they are in the same section.

You can split the section into A and B subsections, keep the subreport in A and move the formula to the B subsection.  That should work.

Comment: i'll try that out mate :)